# Running winform application via console

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a winforms application that takes in input from a gui and runs the logic to give the output.

I want to make a console version of the same application, where I specify the file which has the input values (instead of providing through gui) and run the winform application logic and write the output into a file.

My winform application produces a dll that I wish to use so that any changes in my application is reflected in the console application as well.

Please suggest as to how can I achieve this. I do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do an extra job.

**Option 1: Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()**

You can simplyt use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` to and parse it and use parameters as you need.

For example:

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().ToList()
    .ForEach(x =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(x);
    });
```

For example you can use your program from command line just like this:

- `yourProgram.exe param1 "another param" anotherParam`
- `yourProgram.exe "d:\myfile.txt"`

**Option 2: static void Main(params string[] args)**

Also you can change main signature this way `static void Main(params string[] args)` and use args this way:

```
args.ToList()
    .ForEach(x =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(x);
    });
```

And use it this way:

- `yourProgram.exe param1 "another param" anotherParam`
- `yourProgram.exe "d:\myfile.txt"`

**Note:**

- You can also use command line arguments at debug time. Open project properties, in Debug tab, in Start Option, enter Command line arguments you need. Then simply run the application.
- When using Environment.GetCommandLineArgs the first argument is your application executable address.
- When using args, the first argument is the argument that you passed.

Comment: I have an object that reads the input from the gui but I would like it to read it from the file.

Comment: Simply pass the file address as an arg :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add another project (console application) to your solution and put the IO operations there. The logic stays in the class library.

Comment: Why not just combine them? Using the `args` to either run the `GUI` or a `Console`?

Comment: That's not possible. A week ago a bumped into this problem and because of different "attitudes" of Console and Winform application, you cannot decide which type of application to run after the application has started. You can create or attach the console in Winform application and you can also read command line arguments in Winform, but it will never behave as expected. The attached console never waits on the output of the winform, so the output is mixed into another command promt line.

Comment: You can either `create and attach the console` or `create the winform`. So what doesn't work?

Comment: Attached console does not wait for the end of the application. While the Winform application is running the command prompt can be used to run another commands. If you run Console.ReadLine() in Winform, it starts behaving strangely - you put your input into command prompt. The standard way, when you create console application, is that it waits till the end of console application and you cannot run another commands till then.